# Does Java TreeSet uses less memory than PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, priority-queue, treeset

I was doing this [Question](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/smallest-sequence-with-given-primes/) ans solved it first using PriorityQueue :-

```
public ArrayList<Integer> solve(int A, int B, int C, int D) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>();
    q.add(A);
    q.add(B);
    q.add(C);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(list.size() < D){
        int val = q.poll();
        if(list.size() == 0 || list.get(list.size() - 1) != val)
        list.add(val);
        q.add(val*A);
        q.add(val*B);
        q.add(val*C);
    }

    list.sort(null);
    return list;
}
```

but it gave java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error.
After replacing PriorityQueue with TreeSet, the solution was accepted:-

```
 public ArrayList<Integer> solve(int A, int B, int C, int D) {
    ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>() ;

    TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>() ;
    set.add(A) ;
    set.add(B) ;
    set.add(C) ;

    for(int i = 0; i < D; i++) {
        int temp = set.first() ;
        set.remove(temp) ;
        res.add(temp) ;

        set.add(temp*A) ;
        set.add(temp*B) ;
        set.add(temp*C) ;

    }
    return res ;
}
```

Comment: Don't you think your code would be more readable if you used more meaningful variable names than `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`?

Comment: The function structure was provided by the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't about the data structures. There are a combination of arguments to the first case that can cause this statement to never be true:

```
if(list.size() == 0 || list.get(list.size() - 1) != val)
```

Which means that the loop never terminates and the object `q` grows until you run out of memory. For example try calling with:

`solve(1,1,2,5)`

The difference in memory between the two data structures has no impact in this case. There are some differences to be aware of related to random access and next/previous pointers but it isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

It has basically nothing to do with the amount of memory used, simply your program that uses `PriorityQueue` never ends, adding elements to `PriorityQueue` over and over.

It doesn't end, because of your condition `if(list.size() == 0 || list.get(list.size() - 1) != val)` - it is never satisfied, thus the while loop that checks size of the `list` (that is never changed) is always true, so every loop execution takes 1 element from queue, and then adds 3 elements to it.